# Why Windows 8 PC keeps all logs of deprecated IPv6 prefixes?

Tags: ipv6, prefix

I have a windows 8 pc and my question is this:

I am connected to the Internet and I have a specific global ipv6 prefix. If I reset my router, and by typing the cmd command

netsh> interface ipv6 show addresses

I realised that I have a new preferred prefix, but the old prefix is also shown as deprecated. So if I do this for example 10 times, I will have ten logs with all the deprecated adresses.

Why does pc keeps all the logs of deprecated prefixes? How can I remove deprecated prefixes from the logs?

thanks in advance

Comment: So you get a new IPv6 prefix on every router reboot? …What kind of awful ISP changes customers' addresses randomly like that?

Comment: Yes and this is because customer CPE tha is provided by the ISP takes a new /56 prefix from the ISP-router and therefore allocates a new /64 prefix to my PC...

Comment: What. Why. What's the goddamn point of issuing a whole /56 if it's not going to be static?…

Comment: I do not know the ISP's policy. For very far future needs I suppose !!! I know from forums that RIPE suggests /56 for the ISP allocation towards customer CPE as best practice(!)

Comment: The ISP is absolutely doing the correct thing as clearly indicated by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6177

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a "log". The addresses are still actually *assigned* to the interface.

IPv6 "stateless autoconfiguration" works based on the routers periodically advertising available prefixes, along with their 'valid' and 'preferred' time (since the last announcement). For example, every 10 minutes the router broadcasts that "route 2001:db8::/32 is valid for 4 more hours from now". After the 'preferred' time expires, the prefix is marked as "deprecated" for its remaining 'valid' time.

(Deprecated addresses & prefixes are still considered to be valid!)

So the problem is:

- When you reboot the router, it advertises the new prefix, but cannot withdraw the old one because it doesn't *know* what the old prefix was anymore.
- Even if it did know the old prefix, it couldn't force hosts to immediately discard it as no longer valid. A "Router Advertisement" can only mark a prefix as *deprecated* (so that the OS will no longer use it for connections), but the prefix will always remain valid for at least 2 hours since last announcement, for security reasons ([RFC 4862 page 20](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862#page-20)).

Comment: You are absolutely right! After 2 hours the deprecated prefixes are no longer kept! Thanks again for your concern!

Comment: I should mention that under `interface ipv6` you also have a `delete address` command...